# Unable to install ClickHouse in MacOS due to CANNOT_OPEN_FILE

Tags: clickhouse

While trying to install ClickHouse in a macOS Catalina, doing the following command:

`➜  ~ curl -O 'https://builds.clickhouse.tech/master/macos/clickhouse' && chmod a+x ./clickhouse`

After trying to execute `sudo ./clickhouse install` it will complain with the following message:

```
Copying ClickHouse binary to /usr/bin/clickhouse.new
Code: 76. DB::ErrnoException: Cannot open file /usr/bin/clickhouse.new, errno: 1, strerror: Operation not permitted. (CANNOT_OPEN_FILE) (version 21.10.1.7886 (official build))
```

Why is it failing even if I sudo the command? Are there any other commands required before trying to install ClickHouse?

Comment: It's a MacOs, you cannot install CH as a service where. It does not work like this in MacOs.

Comment: Why do you need to run CH server in MacOS?

Comment: Which is the best way to run a local instance "standalone" for quick testing, queries and play a bit around with it? @DennyCrane

Comment: ./clickhouse server --config config.xml

Comment: but the best way is to use docker and normal CH for linux. MacOS clickhouse build is incomplete and missing some modules, mysql, hdfs, ...

Comment: Taking note of that, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 10):

`/usr/bin` is protected by Apple's SIP (System Integrity Protection) mechanism. You can install clickhouse into specific (not protected) directory by passing `--binary-path` flag. This way you won't have to disable SIP.

For example, on MacOS you can install into `/usr/local/bin`, which is not protected, by using this command: `sudo ./clickhouse install --binary-path /usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: if you use this solution, since `sudo clickhouse start` (to start the clickhouse server) [assumes](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/programs/install/Install.cpp#L218) your clickhouse binary is in /usr/bin, you'll need to use `sudo clickhouse start --binary-path=/usr/local/bin` when running that command (or set an alias for clickhouse server: `alias clickhouse-server="/usr/local/bin/clickhouse-server"`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a rootless (SIP) mechanism that Apple has added to the new version of the system. The basic purpose of SIP is to prevent programs from obtaining root privileges and modifying several key system directories. It can indeed play a certain protective role.
The main directories to be protected are:

- /System
- /usr
- /bin
- /sbin and preinstalled apps

Close the SIp in the kernel:

1. Restart the computer and press command+R until the Apple logo appears. At this time, you will enter Recovery Mode.
2. After selecting a language, enter recovery mode, find Utilities in the above menu, and find Terminal in it;
3. Open the terminal and enter the following command to close SIP;

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the problem by installing ClickHouse this way here: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/quick-start/#1-start-clickhouse.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use docker to install clickhouse server/client.

```
docker pull yandex/clickhouse-server
docker pull yandex/clickhouse-client
docker run -it --rm --link some-clickhouse-server:clickhouse-server yandex/clickhouse-client --host clickhouse-server
```

Comment: The reply does not answer the above question, it just bypasses the problem